# Restrict android APKs to only Phone using support screen

Tags: android, android-multiple-apk

I'm working on an application where I want to have two different APK's for Phone and Tablet. How do I restrict apk in mainifest file using support screen. I'm very confused with new attributes like android:requiresSmallestWidthDp and android:largestWidthLimitDp. Please help me out.

Comment: first you have to define, what is `phone` and what is `tablet`. How can you determine it? By which parameter?

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention like this in manifest

```
<manifest ... >
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
...
<application ... >
    ...
</application>
```

have a look at  [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Comment: I want to consider only 10 inch tablets and anything below 10 inch is Phone.

Comment: for 10 inch replace 600 with 720

Comment: and what happens if I just specify  android:xlargeScreens="true" and rest all false

Comment: How to check because these filters applied only for play store listing so how do test it. I know we can check using aapt command but not sure how to test.

Comment: I'm confused because compatible-screens tag is used for restricting an apk to phone and support-screens tag is used for restricting for Tablets

Comment: and minSdk = 16 in my application so I'm assuming android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720" is sufficient. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: minSdk =16 means your app is restricted to android version above 4.1 Jelly Bean